# Django: Store multiple & dynamically ordered model sequence

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say, a user has video clips and images, both of them with their corresponding model, `VideoClipModel` and `ImageModel`.

Now i'm adding a new functionality where a user can combine clips and images to create a "final" video. Now what i need is to create a model where i can store the sequence of the video clips and images. Anyone has idea how to to this?

For example: A user wants to create a final video with the following item sequence:

```
Image1 -> VideoClip1 -> Image2 -> VideoClip2 -> VideoClip3 -> Image3 -> Image1
```

What i want to do is to create a model where i can store the sequence selected

I though about creating my VideoFinalModel with two m2m fields to ImageModel and VideoClipModel and a charfield which would store the order in a way similar  to this:

```
image_1, video_1, image_2, video_2, video_3, image_3, image_1
```

So the models would look like:

```
def VideoFinal(...):
    videos = models.ManyToManyFIeld("VideoClips")
    images = models.ManyToManyFIeld("Images")
    order = models.CharField()

def Images(...):
    """ A bunch of fields here """

def VideoClips(...):
    """ A bunch of different fields here """
```

Now, this would do what i want... however i dont believe this is how it should be done.

How can i do this in the pythonic way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a model `VideoComponent` with a position field as well as foreign keys to `VideoClipModel` and `ImageModel`. Then a `Video` model would have a many to many field to `VideoComponent`.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    components = models.ManyToManyField('VideoComponent')

class VideoComponent(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey('ImageModel')
    video_clip = models.ForeignKey('VideoClipModel ')
    position = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
```

Get the ordered components:

```
 video.components.all()
```

Also check out django-mptt for storing hierarchical data:

[The problem which django-mptt solves.](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html#the-problem)

[Project github.](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/)

Comment: seems to be what i'm looking for!